# How to add maven/repo libraries to old project without gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio

Where can I include online (maven etc) libraries/repo in Android Studio 2.0 **without build.gradle**?

Before it was somethere in add library dialogs, but now i can add local jars only. But how to add online repositories to old projects without gradle?

Note, i do not want to include all library project/source, import module etc. Just want to link online libs as before.

Comment: I am not aware of any options here. IMHO, if you do not want to use Gradle, do not use Android Studio. Use IntelliJ IDEA or some other IDE.

Comment: pity but you're right